# why doesn smarty not load a template file which is placed in another template file

Tags: smarty

i am trying to load a template file which is included in another template file and both exist in same folder,the html part is loading however template file within is not..
The manual suggests this
     `{include file="file:C/my/path/to/folder/product_list.tpl"}`
 and few other options but nothing is working out,code looks like

```
{*first_page.tpl*}
 <p>....few lines here </p>
 {include file="product_list.tpl"}
```

any pointers to fix this??

Comment: do other smarty instructions work? does it show any error message? does the product_list.tpl have any content or any conditions? is templates_c writable?

Comment: @Borgtex if i add other template file it works fine , and no it does not show any error message, yes the product_list.tpl has contents, and the first_page.tpl should fill the contentscell if the visitor is not browsing any department or categories, i can post the code if it helps to figure out a solution

Comment: thank you for your time,@Borgtex it was mistake i looked it up i was calling a wrong stored proecdure to load the front_page.tpl so the mess,fixed it now its all n good :-)